# File browser in the console using Visual C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-console

I have to make a kind of a file browser as a Windows console application with Visual C++. What libraries and functions should I use? I don't know how to start.

Comment: You will find that stack overflow is a terrible place to start your research. It is much better suited to detailing or filling holes in research. That said, start by listing directories. If your copy of visual studio is really up to date you may have access to the [`<filesystem>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) (formally added to C++ in late 2017). If not, [FindFirstFileW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) and [FindNextFileW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew) 1/2

Comment: 2/2 are likely your friends. Note I've linked to the wide character versions. It's 2018 and no one should be learning with the ANSI versions.